# Making Exponent the Subject When Equation Contains Multiple Unknowns

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

** Sorry if some of the terminology is wrong here, I am but a novice **

I want to make $g$ the subject of the following equation

$x_T=x_1 e^{g(T-1)}$

I have the answer, which is given as

$g=\cfrac{\ln(x_T)-\ln(x_1)}{T-1}$

But I would like to understand how this answer was obtained.

Unfortunately, if you Google something like 'exponential into log form,' you will just run into rudimentary explanations of how to convert exponentials into logs, something like:

$3^x=9\rightarrow x=\log_3 9$

I cannot seem to find any examples of how to make the exponent the subject when the equation contains multiple variables. Hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Try making $e^g$ the subject first, and then see if you can apply the "exponential into logs" rule. Also from the solution you posted, it seems as though $(T-1)$ belongs in the exponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_1 \ne 0$we can write the equation as
$$
\frac{x_T}{x_1}=e^{g(T-1)}
$$
so, using the definition of logarithm, we have
$$
\log \frac{x_T}{x_1}=g(T-1)
$$
and using the formula
$$
\log \frac{a}{b}=\log a -\log b
$$
you can find the result.